# Excel if funktion

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following formula to search for the word "IT". If found, it returns the word "Red"; otherwise "Blue".

How can I do the same, but searching for more than one word?

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("IT";D5);0);"Red";"Blue")
```

Comment: I happen to know what OM, OMFEL & SÖK means as I'm finnish, but the rest of the non-scandinavian world probably does not - you should translate them to english.

Comment: It is too localized. Use english equvalents of Excel functions.

Comment: Sorry for that!

Did not think about the translation of the script, took it directly from excel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("IT",D5)),ISERROR(SEARCH("otherWord",D5))),
"Neither of the two words are there","One or both words are there")
```

Comment: It works just fine at my end. You may need to: translate function names to Swedish, replace `,` with `;`, replace `Neither of the two words are there` with `Red`, etc. Unfortunately I'm not a psychic, so I can't help based on *"I can not get this to work"*.

Comment: I write this:

=OM(OCH(OMFEL(SÖK("IT";D5));OMFEL(SÖK("otherWord";D5)));
"Red";"Blue")

and get the following message:
Not enough arguments specified for this function

Comment: That's because you wrote `OMFEL`, which is `IFERROR`, which is not the same as what I wrote: `ISERROR`. I'm not sure what that function's name is in Swedish... `ÄRFEL` maybe? Also please note: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote